# How to use multiple instances of gcc?

Tags: gcc, symbolic-link, update-alternatives

I have both gcc 4.7.3 and 4.8.1 installed

But on running gcc --version I get

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I am an Ubuntu newbie and I don't know much about updating symbolic-links...

I searched the Internet, and found out about update-alternatives but was reluctant to use it...

Please can someone help me in choosing 4.8 over 4.7 & also tell me is it bad to have 2 versions of same gcc?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to let `update-alternatives` to know that you have 2 C/C++ compilers, create a record for each one, and then configure which one you want to use. This is done with the following:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.7
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 40 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

From this point forward, the only thing required when switching compilers is this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

Source: http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/2011-12-24_GCCv47/.

Comment: Thank You Sir for helping :)
 Now whenever I type sudo update-alternatives --config gcc

It presents me with 3 choices 

But sir Can you explain me about those priorities and status modes ??