# Downloaded g++ 4.8 from the PPA but can't set it as default?

Tags: gcc, g++, software-installation

I have downloaded g++ 4.8 on Ubuntu 12.10 by doing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.8
```

but when I do:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

to switch g++ versions it says:

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for g++.
```

However if I do:

```
g++ --version
```

it says:

```
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How do I set my g++ 4.8 installation to be the default g++?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you must discover where are your 4.8 binaries of all the tools:

```
$ which gcc-4.8
/usr/bin/gcc-4.8
$ which g++-4.8
/usr/bin/g++-4.8
$ ls /usr/bin/*-4.8
/usr/bin/cpp-4.8         /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-cpp-4.8
/usr/bin/g++-4.8         /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-4.8
/usr/bin/gcc-4.8         /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-4.8
/usr/bin/gcc-ar-4.8      /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-4.8
/usr/bin/gcc-nm-4.8      /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-4.8
/usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-4.8  /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-4.8
/usr/bin/gcov-4.8
```

So, we have all our binaries, now lets see if some symlinks are available for such binaries:

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ ls -l gcc* cpp g++
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 sep 18 14:02 cpp -> cpp-4.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 abr 22  2013 g++ -> g++-4.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 sep 18 14:02 gcc -> gcc-4.7
```

As we can see, only `cpp`, `g++` and `gcc` has symbolic links. We have two options here.

### Symlinking

We replace the symlinks with ours, removing the actuals first:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/cpp /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/g++
```

Then creating ours

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/cpp-4.8 /usr/bin/cpp
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 /usr/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.8 /usr/bin/g++
```

To revert it back use the same commands but with 4.7 or 4.6 instead

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/cpp /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/g++
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/cpp-4.7 /usr/bin/cpp
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 /usr/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.7 /usr/bin/g++
```

Comment: When I did: ls -l gcc* cpp g++ it returned: ls: cannot access gcc*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access cpp: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access g++: No such file or directory

Comment: No apology required :) Once I call the remove function it works,  but when I go to create "our" symlinks it says: sudo ln -s -T /usr/bin/cpp /usr/bin/cpp-4.8
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/bin/cpp-4.8': File exists

Comment: (I called the rm command twice just so on the second time it confirmed/complained that the existing links were in fact deleted)

Comment: **This is a terrible idea**. There are many programs who use `gcc` to compile kernel modules and some of them (e.g. Nvidia) will silently crash when the `gcc` they call will not be the one the kernel was compiled with.

Comment: @nbubis well, the question is "How do I set my g++ 4.8 installation to be the default g++?", so, one should presume whoever does this, they know what they are doing, no? On the other hand, what alternative can you propose?

Answer (score 18):

You need to let `update-alternatives` to know that you have 2 C++ compilers, create a record for each one, and then configure which one you want to use. This is done with the following:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.6.3 60
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 40
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

From this point forward, the only thing required when switching compilers is this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

See `man update-alternatives` for more info.

<sup>Source: [How to use multiple instances of gcc?](https://askubuntu.com/a/313313/147044)</sup>

Comment: @Braiam It can be done in the same way with any package.

Comment: Can someone elaborate on the 60 and 40? Ive seen this in lots of places

Comment: @user997112 I suggest you to read the man, but, if you like more 70 and 30, then use 70 and 30...

Comment: oh- percentages of some kind

Comment: @user997112 these are priority numbers, and are only relevant when using --auto. you can see some examples using `update-alternatives --display editor`

Comment: On 12.04 I get: update-alternatives: error: alternative g++ can't be master: it is a slave of gcc

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 10):

[This is the great description](http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/2011-12-24_GCCv47/) and step-by-step instruction how to create and manage master and slave (gcc and g++) alternatives.

Shortly, it's

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.7 
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 40 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: You're right. I added the essential part

Comment: Saved my day with that slave stuff. tx