# gcc --version and package version is not the same

Tags: apt, compiling, gcc

When i enter following command in the terminal:

```
gcc --version
```

It's output something like this:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04) 6.5.0 20181026
...
```

But when i enter below command to see version of the installed gcc package:

```
apt-cache show gcc | grep Version
```

I see this:

```
Version: 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.2
Version: 4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2.1
Version: 4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2
```

Is it normal?

Which version used by software that needs gcc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc is installed on your Ubuntu (18.04, 18.10 or 19.04) as well gcc-6 and possibly some other gcc version(s). Although gcc is installed, gcc-6 is currently the default version of gcc. To show all the versions of gcc installed on your OS, run the following command:

```
apt policy gcc gcc-5 gcc-6 gcc-7 gcc-8 gcc-9
```

As you can see from the results of the above command, there are several different alternative versions of gcc in the default Ubuntu repositories, and multiple versions of gcc can be installed alongside each other. You can select which version of gcc to use if multiple versions are installed by following the instructions in [How to use multiple instances of gcc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313288).

Comment: Although this probably is right, I don't see how in answers OPs question.

Comment: @SorenA After adding the last sentence, I'm explaining two things. 1. Why there are two different non-matching versions of gcc returned by `gcc --version` and `apt-cache show gcc | grep Version`. 2. How to choose which gcc version to use if multiple versions of gcc are installed.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/gcc` is normally a symbolic link, and it normally points to the default current version of `gcc` for your system - which in your case appears to be `gcc-7.4.0`

If the link is pointing to a different version, that's likely because it has been linked manually using `ln`, or via the `update-alternatives` system.

Software doesn't "need" `gcc` at runtime - so it would only affect what version of the compiler is used when you build software from sources.

Comment: Yes, you'r right. There is no need for runtime purposes. I want to install cuda. As it refered [https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html]here, cuda needs gcc as a prerequisites.