# How do I use older gcc on Ubuntu for one particular build without affecting the system?

Tags: 19.04, gcc, alias

On Ubuntu 19.04, I have to build a project that requires an older gcc version that one installed in my system. For certain reasons, I cannot modify makefiles; during the build, gcc command must invoke older gcc, not the default version. How do I achieve that without breaking the default gcc currently installed in the system?

Comment: Does the software's build process invoke `gcc` directly, or does the makefile do something like setting `CC := gcc` in which case you may be able to override it on the command line like `make CC=path/to/old/gcc`?

Comment: @steeldriver Through an internal variable which cannot be controlled from outside. Currently I just fixed it in the makefile with gcc-6 instead of gcc, but as soon as I start working with the repository I'm going to have a headache.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multiple instances of gcc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313288/how-to-use-multiple-instances-of-gcc)

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, they call gcc through their own internal variable where they also add some flags. After I overrode it from command line:

```
make CCCMD='gcc-6 ...'
```

it got fixed.

I just forgot about overriding feature of make.